# "where" clause in numpy-1.13 ufuncs

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I occasionally use the `where` clause in numpy's ufuncs. For example, the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
np.sqrt(a, where=a>0) * (a>0)
```

In Numpy 1.12 and earlier, this used to give me square root values where possible and zero otherwise.

Recently, though, I upgraded to numpy 1.13. The code above now gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Automatic allocation was requested for an iterator operand, and it was flagged as readable, but buffering  without delayed allocation was enabled
```

I thought that this was exactly how the `where` clause was supposed to be used, but perhaps I was wrong. So I have two questions: first, what's wrong with this code; and second, what is the recommended way of achieving my goal?

Comment: This `where` is documented in the general `ufunc` optional keywords section: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments

Comment: The error looks like something at `nditer` would issue.  I'd look on github for changes or issues related to that.

Comment: This message is issued by line 1004 in numpy/numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_constr.c, the `nditer` source code.

Comment: There tests for the `where` parameter in `numpy/core/tests/test_ufunc.py` all include an `out` parameter.  Does including an `out` array make a change in this 1.13 error?

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah, I found the same bit of source code by googling the error message, but really don't have a clue where to go next. I have never looked at numpy's internals before. I was hoping that some of you gurus might know :)

Comment: @hpaulj That seems to fix it. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I assume it's a side effect of some other change, and these tests aren't comprehensive enough to catch it.

Comment: thank u .. it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference: this turned out to be a bug in numpy. It [has been fixed](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9335) for the next numpy release, presumably version 1.13.1.

A workaround fix for 1.13.0 is to explicitly provide an `out` parameter to the ufunc. In the example above, `np.sqrt(a, where=a>0, out=np.zeros(a.shape))` works.

Comment: A discussion of this weird behavoiur can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544189/what-additional-work-is-done-by-np-power). Essentially because you don't give an out array a np.empty array is used as out array