# What additional work is done by np.power?

Tags: python, numpy

I realised that `np.power(a, b)` is slower than `np.exp(b * np.log(a))`:

```
import numpy as np
a, b = np.random.random((2, 100000))
%timeit np.power(a, b) # best of 3: 4.16 ms per loop
%timeit np.exp(b * np.log(a)) # best of 3: 1.74 ms per loop
```

The results are the same (with a few numerical errors of order 1e-16).

What additional work is done in `np.power`? Furthermore, how can I find an answer to these kind of questions myself?

Comment: The entire source code is available at https://github.com/numpy/numpy, I found several `power` functions there and can't be sure which is which (I don't invest time in looking through it) but you could try there, just search with quotes "def power" as a start

Comment: @OferSadan Can you tell me a little bit more, where you found these `power`functions, can't find them myself (turns put NumPy is really big...)

Comment: At the top of the [github page](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) there is a search field. Typing `"def power"` finds 3 hits.

Comment: Exactly what @unutbu said

Comment: Side note: `%timeit a**b` gives the same time as `%timeit np.power(a,b)` for me.

Comment: So does `%timeit pow(a, b)` and `%timeit pow(a, b, 3)` - looks like `np.power` is implementing the ternery operation, which might shave off some performance.

Comment: For people suffering from the same confusion I did, this is the element wise operation $y[i,j]=a[i,j]^{b[i,j]}$ and not the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Under the hood](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3b7908d299fc3287486bbe453e2335c1fa50fc29/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src) both expressions call the respective C functions `pow` or `exp` and `log` and [running a profiling on those in C++](https://gist.github.com/adler-j/a440d4539ad1bbaa7dc3e2727f93e8b1), without any numpy code, gives:

```
pow      : 286 ms
exp(log) :  93 ms
```

This is consistent with the numpy timings. It thus seems like the primary difference is that the C function `pow` is slower than `exp(log)`.

Why? It seems that part of the reson is that the expressions are not equivalent for all input. For example, with negative `a` and integer `b`, `power` works while `exp(log)` fails:

```
>>> np.power(-2, 2)
4
>>> np.exp(2 * np.log(-2))
nan
```

Another example is `0 ** 0`:

```
>>> np.power(0, 0)
1
>>> np.exp(0 * np.log(0))
nan
```

Hence, the `exp(log)` trick only works on a subset of inputs, while `power` works on all (valid) inputs.

In addition to this, `power` is guaranteed to give full precision according to the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), while `exp(log)` may suffer from rounding errors.

Comment: And as for OP's question about finding answer yourself - I checked debugger for type of: `np.power`, `np.log`, `np.exp` - it was `ufunc`  and in the documentation of numpy I found that these are defined in `generate_umath.py` as: `pow`, `log` and `npy_ObjectPower`. The last one is actually C function found in [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numpy/numpy/d46df62746995481439b650790589e60a8070172/numpy/core/src/umath/funcs.inc.src) and returns `PyNumber_Power` and this is actually Python's `pow` [according to docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html)

Comment: Moreover, `pow()` always gives you the full accuracy of double precision floating point numbers, even in cases where the combination of `exp()` and `log()` loses a few digits.

Comment: You can actually do the "log trick" with negatives if you assign `a = a.astype(complex)` and pull the real part, but you lose the speed advantage

Comment: Sure, but you also need to handle `a = b = 0`!

Comment: True, although`0**0=1` is more convention than identity, and technically `0**0=nan` is also correct.  It's just not very useful!

Comment: Also, it looks like `np.lib.scimath.power` does the "log trick" as it checks for and converts negatives to complex before passing to . . . some recursive bitwise c-function I can't follow. But the conversion check seems to slow it down below `np.power`

Comment: Seems like `pow` and `np.power` are conforming to the [IEEE 754-2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#IEEE_floating_point_standard) floating point standard function recommendations for `pow` and `powr` accordingly.